# Create 64 bit .so file using MUPDF 1.2 or below in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, 64-bit, mupdf

In my android application, Im using MuPDF 1.2 version which is having 32 bit binaries only.Now the Google Play store is forcing to update the old app to 64 bit compatible.

Is it possible to compile the old mupdf 1.2 to create a 64 bit .so file ?

Any thought is appreciated.

Comment: Given that the [source code is available](https://mupdf.com/downloads/index.html) at least make an attempt.

Comment: the problem is that latest version is not compatible with older versions. it seems like they rewrote it and now latest version api missing all older api calls altogether

Comment: @Adviser2010 you are correct, we need to rewrite.

Comment: did anymone get the 64 bit yet ?

Comment: @AnassBoukalane I created that from the new MuPdf Library. Still dont know why people downvotes this question?

Comment: Can you send it to me please ?

Comment: You can do that from the latest mupdf source code which you can download from MuPdf.I will add the steps for creating 64-bit soon.

Comment: @KP_ i need to test it first , cos i am using on old version of the library , i have to check compatibility, thanks

Answer (score 0):

we were able to compile 1.4 version of mupdf but got the following problem: native drawpage() function call crashes if there is no delay before call. After adding a small delay it works when app is running in debug mode. As soon as we release it - it crashes too on drawpage() call and delay doesn't help.

So, if someone can shed some light to this mysterious problem, I'd appreciate it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Sorry for downvoting!

Answer (score -1):

We have the same problem. We tried to compile directly from source code of version 1.2 but the original NDK compiler 5 does not support 64bit compilation, while newer (or the latest) NDKs give a specific error in compilation. Did you succeeded somehow?

Comment: You can able to create 64 bit version using the latest Mupuf version in android.I did that recently.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.Sorry for downvoting!